# MYSQL query that displays: the first order for each customer

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me...
Based on Northwind database http://www.pilpoils.be/demos/northwind-db/assets/12f53c79/northwind.gif, 
I want to write a MYSQL query that displays: the first order for each customer.
I tried but i have difficulty...here is my query:

```
select top 1 * from orders inner join customers on orders.customerid=customers.customerid
```

thnx to all

Comment: "orderDate" in "orders" table - does it keep date and time ? or only date ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from Customers AS c 
    INNER JOIN `Orders` AS o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN 
        ( SELECT CustomerID, min(OrderDate) AS mod FROM `Orders` GROUP BY CustomerID ) AS mTable
        ON mTable.mod = OrderDate AND mTable.CustomerID = C.CustomerID;
```